# If I am an administrator, can I use IEPassView to see password of another user account?

Tags: windows-7, passwords

I can use IEPassView to see my own password. There is another account that I want to see. It's my own but I forget the password. I want to see the password stored for ie there.

Because I am an administrator, I can just delete password for that account. However, doing so would delete all stored password.

So I wonder, given that I am an administrator anyway, how can I use http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/internet_explorer_password.html to check pass for another user account without having to login as that user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft requires](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/risks-resetting-password#1TC=windows-7) that you either know the password, or have a password reset disk for that account.

Since you're implying that you don't, what you're actually asking is, how do I crack the Security Accounts Manager (SAM) cryptography.  I'm not sure if cracking is something they support here, but the most common tool for this task is [Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/).